# Rotating UV with precision

Tags: uv, transforms

I keep running into a problem: How can I rotate an UV island by exactly 90 or 180 degrees? The same applies for scaling it to double in size, etc.

Comment: When using nearly any tool in Blender, Rotate in particularly, you can [enter numerical value of the exact amount of desired effect](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/rotate.html?highlight=rotate#fine-tuning-the-rotation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the part of the UV map selected that you want to rotate, hit <kbd>R</kbd> to enter rotation mode, then type the number of degrees with the numpad, for example <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to rotate it 90°. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> to apply it, or just left click.

You can also scale the selection with <kbd>S</kbd> and then entering a numerical value, for example <kbd>2</kbd> to make it twice as large, or <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to make it half the size.

You can also move the selection along the X or Y axis by hitting <kbd>G</kbd> to grab it, then constraining it to the X or Y axis with <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd>, then entering the number of units you want it to move.

This also works in the 3D viewport. If you look at the bottom of the current viewport while doing a resize, scale, or movement operation, you can see the values you have entered in the bar beneath the viewport.