# How I can rotate `unwrap`, exactly?

Tags: uv

How I can rotate `unwrap`, exactly, for example some menu or box to enter for example 90 degrees ?. This is possible?.

Sorry for my English I hope you can understand me.

I leave a picture hope it will help me understand.

[image]

Blender version : 2.72

Comment: Here is the solution, -> http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/rotating-uv-with-precision?rq=1  not before I found with the search, but not if delete this answer or mark it as duplicate, I do not know how these cases are handled in Blender Exchange